# How to upload a Folder using az dls fs upload

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-cli2

I'm trying to upload a folder (which contains ~100 files) to Azure Data Lake Store.
However, when using

```
az dls fs upload --account $adls_account --source-path $src_dir --destination-path $dest_dir --overwrite --thread-count $thread_count --debug
```

My source folder is:

```
Test1/Testfolder2
```

Testfolder2 contains close to 100 files. So i would like to upload the folder Testfolder2 as such.

Rather than uploading the folder, it is going inside the folder Testfolder2 and upload the files altogether rather than the folder itself.

can someone help on how to resolve this.

Thasnk,
Arjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload data to Data Lake Store directly at the root level or to a folder that you created within the account.

For more details, refer "[Upload data to a Data Lake Store account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-cli-2.0#upload-data-to-a-data-lake-store-account)".